# Getting exception in getDatabase called recursively in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, illegalstateexception

I am trying to implement DBHelper in android for my project here how i implemented it
I want to do is , On runtime decide which database you want to create for this i implemented class `abstract class SQLiteDBService` extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`
which is inherited by two classes `LocalSQLiteDBService` and `RestServerSQLiteDBService` runtime i decided which to call and `override` the `onCreate` method in both classes with different db and tables,

```
package db_service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.Iterator;
import db_table.TABLES;

/**
 * Created by Dipak on 3/5/2016.
 */
public abstract class SQLiteDBService extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final String TAG_DB_OPERATION    = "DB Operation";

    private static final int    DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private SQLiteDatabase  m_sqlLiteDatabase;

    public SQLiteDBService(Context context,String database_name) {
        super(context, database_name, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        Log.i(TAG_DB_OPERATION, "Creating Database...");
    }

    public void OpenWrite() {
        m_sqlLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void OpenRead() {
        m_sqlLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
    }


    public void Close() {
        this.close();
    }

    //TODO:it will get called for every application launch
    public void CreateTable(JSONObject obj) {
        try {
            int i=0;
            JSONObject tables = obj.getJSONObject("tables");
            Log.i(TAG_DB_OPERATION ,"Tables:" + tables.toString());
            Iterator<String> table = tables.keys();
            while(table.hasNext()){
                String tableName = table.next();
                Log.i(TAG_DB_OPERATION,"Table Name:" + tableName);
                JSONArray tableColumns = tables.getJSONArray(tableName);
                Log.i(TAG_DB_OPERATION, "Table Columns:" + tableColumns.toString());
                String create_table_query = "create table " + tableName + "(";
                for(i = 0 ; i < tableColumns.length();i++) {
                    JSONObject column = tableColumns.getJSONObject(i);
                    Log.i(TAG_DB_OPERATION,"Column:" + column.toString());
                    create_table_query += column.getString("name") + " " + column.getString("type");
                    if(i != tableColumns.length()-1){
                        create_table_query += ",";
                    }
                }
                create_table_query += ");";
                CreateTable(create_table_query);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("DB Operation","Something wrong failed to create table");
        }
    }

    public void CreateTable(String createTableQuery) {
        Log.i(TAG_DB_OPERATION,"CreateTable" +createTableQuery);
        OpenWrite();
        m_sqlLiteDatabase.execSQL(  createTableQuery);
        Log.i(TAG_DB_OPERATION,"Done Creating Table");
    }

    public Cursor ReadTable(String tableName, String[] columns) {
        Log.i(TAG_DB_OPERATION,"ReadTable");
        OpenRead();
        return m_sqlLiteDatabase.query(tableName, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    }
}
```

Below is the code for my class which will override `onCreate` method

```
package db_service;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;
import db_table.TABLES;

/**
 * Created by Dipak on 3/5/2016.
 */
public class LocalSQLiteDBService extends SQLiteDBService {
    private static final String TAG_LOCAL_DB_OPERATION = "DB Operation Local";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME       = "LOCAL.DB";
    public LocalSQLiteDBService(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.i(TAG_LOCAL_DB_OPERATION,"onCreate");
        //CreateTable(TABLES.LOCAL_DB.CREDENTIAL_STORE.getJson());
        CreateTable(TABLES.LOCAL_DB.CREDENTIAL_STORE.CREATE_TABLE_QUERY);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public boolean isCredentialsPresent() {
        Log.i(TAG_LOCAL_DB_OPERATION,"isCredentialsPresent");
        return GetStoredCredentials().getCount() != 0;
    }

    public Cursor GetStoredCredentials(){
        Log.i(TAG_LOCAL_DB_OPERATION,"isCredentialsPresent");
        String[] columns = {
                TABLES.LOCAL_DB.CREDENTIAL_STORE.ID,
                TABLES.LOCAL_DB.CREDENTIAL_STORE.USER_ID,
                TABLES.LOCAL_DB.CREDENTIAL_STORE.PASSWORD
            };
        return ReadTable(TABLES.LOCAL_DB.CREDENTIAL_STORE.CREATE_TABLE_QUERY,columns);
    }
}
```

Heres how i used it

```
LocalSQLiteDBService m_SqLiteDBServiceLocal;
m_SqLiteDBServiceLocal = new LocalSQLiteDBService(this);
m_SqLiteDBServiceLocal.isCredentialsPresent()
```

Below is the exception i am getting

```
03-06 14:21:59.816 30879-30879/? I/DB Operation Local: onCreate
03-06 14:21:59.816 30879-30879/? I/DB Operation: CreateTablecreate table credentials_store(id number,user_id number,password text);
03-06 14:21:59.817 30879-30879/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.buk, PID: 30879
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.buk/com.buk.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getDatabase called recursively
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getDatabase called recursively
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:203)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
                                                       at db_service.SQLiteDBService.OpenWrite(SQLiteDBService.java:33)
                                                       at db_service.SQLiteDBService.CreateTable(SQLiteDBService.java:77)
                                                       at db_service.LocalSQLiteDBService.onCreate(LocalSQLiteDBService.java:25)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:187)
                                                       at db_service.SQLiteDBService.OpenRead(SQLiteDBService.java:37)
                                                       at db_service.SQLiteDBService.ReadTable(SQLiteDBService.java:84)
                                                       at db_service.LocalSQLiteDBService.GetStoredCredentials(LocalSQLiteDBService.java:45)
                                                       at db_service.LocalSQLiteDBService.isCredentialsPresent(LocalSQLiteDBService.java:35)
                                                       at com.buk.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:51)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call getWritableDB if its already been called without closing the original one.  In onCreate, you're passed a writable db.  Use that one, and pass it to your helper functions.  Don't have your helper functions request a new one.

Comment: But i want to hide the implementation of m_sqlLiteDatabase object in the same class , other wise whenever i call CreateTable i have to pass m_sqlLiteDatabase  object, how can i do this

Comment: Write 2 versions of Create table.  One takes a db as a parameter, one doesn't.  The one that doesn't calls getWritableDatabase and then calls the one that takes a parameter, passing it in.  Although really I'm not too certain if your architecture as a whole makes sense here, but I don't know enough about what you're trying to do to say that for sure.

Comment: Actually i think i understood problem is i am checking Credential Table has a value or not, But when its firs-time application load it goes for Read Table which maked it getReadable and then as db not exists it is redirecting to onCreate method which in again trying for getWritable when it is in getReadable

Comment: Thanks Gabe Sechan :)